# Автоматическое увеличение статистики

Tags: jquery

На сайте есть статистика , которая по факту берется из бд , хочу сделать так что бы эта статистика не бралась из бд а автоматически прибавляла цифры , например сколько пользователей зарегистрировано . Нужно что б каждые 20 минут прибавлялось + например 5 и так постоянно . Помогите кому не сложно в js очень плохо разбираюсь , гуглю но что-то подходящего ответа нет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const element = document.querySelector('.user_statistic');
let user_statistic = 20;

setInterval(() => {
    user_statistic += 5;
    updateBlockText();
}, 5 * 1000 /* 1000 * 60 * 20 */);

function updateBlockText() {
    element.innerText = user_statistic;
}

updateBlockText();
```

```html
<div class="user_statistic"></div>
```

Comment: @Sevastopol' свободного времени стало маловато, но я думаю что SO не заброшу никогда уж точно.